# add/remove active class for ul list with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove and set an active class for a list item every time it's clicked. It's currently removing the selected active class but isn't setting it.  Any idea what I'm missing?

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class='nav-header'>Test</li>
  <li class="active"><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="page3.php">Page 3</li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
 $('.nav-list').click(function() {

    //console.log("Clicked");
    $('.nav-list li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Just a thought, but could it be because you're adding the active class to the actual list, and not the list object within the list? You remove from .nav-list li, but add to .nav-list

Comment: if you log `$(this)` you'll see that your event refers to the list itself. you have to refer to the listelement `$('.nav-list li')` or better use event delegation as desrcibed by @minitech below

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`this` will point to the `<ul>` selected by `.nav-list`. You can use delegation instead!

```
$('.nav-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('.nav-list li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 19):

you can use **siblings** and **removeClass** method

```
$('.nav-link li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I know this is coming up on almost a year old, but this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

```
 $('.nav-list li').click(function() {

    $('.nav-list li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

In your context `$(this)` will points to the `UL` element not the `Li`. Hence you are not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

I used this:

```js
$('.nav-list li.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

Since the active class is in the `<li>` element and what is clicked is the `<a>` element, the first line removes `.active` from all `<li>` and the second one (again, `$(this)` represents `<a>` which is the clicked element) adds `.active` to the direct parent, which is `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have div element with same class. Now I added the active class on it using jquery check the code.

**div element**

```
<div class="previewBox" id="first_div">
 ...
</div>

<div class="previewBox" id="second_div">
 ...
</div>

<div class="previewBox" id="third_div">
 ...
</div>
```

**jquery code**

```
$(".previewBox").click(function () {
   $(".previewBox.active").removeClass('active')
   $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

**css**

```
.active {
  background-color:#e9f1f5;
  border-left:4px solid #024a81;
}
```

**Demo**
[click_this](https://codepen.io/neeraj1005/pen/dyWmbqM)

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cliked').click(function() {
        $(".cliked").removeClass("liactive");
        $(this).addClass("liactive");
    });
});
```

```css
.liactive {
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul
  className="sidebar-nav position-fixed "
  style="height:450px;overflow:scroll"
>
    <li>
        <a className="cliked liactive" href="#">
            check Kyc Status
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a className="cliked" href="#">
            My Investments
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a className="cliked" href="#">
            My SIP
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a className="cliked" href="#">
            My Tax Savers Fund
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a className="cliked" href="#">
            Transaction History
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a className="cliked" href="#">
            Invest Now
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a className="cliked" href="#">
            My Profile
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a className="cliked" href="#">
            FAQ`s
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a className="cliked" href="#">
            Suggestion Portfolio
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a className="cliked" href="#">
            Bluk Lumpsum / Bulk SIP
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>;
```