# Indentify tab with aria-selected=true and change tab background color in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, wai-aria

We have a glossary page that lets you select from over a hundred different tabs with different glossary terms and the definition will appear in the definition div tag depending on which tab you select. That's all well and good, but the tab itself has no identifier to let you know which term you are on. What I'd like to do is have the background color of the tab change color for the term of the definition that is currently displayed.

In the below example, the only way I can think of to make the background color for the `<li>` tag change color is to go by the `aria-selected="true"` tag. What would be the best way in jquery to go through all the tabs and look for the `aria-selected="true"` and then addClass "active" to the `<li>` to change the background color for just that tab? And then if it is `aria-selected="false"` obviously removeClass "active".

Yes, it is possible to have more than one `aria-selected="true"` on the page because there are different groups, each with its own div display window which is separated by the id tags.

```
<ul>
<li class="tab-item tab_id_01a active" role="none"><a href="#id_01a" id="label_id_01a" class="tab-link" role="menuitem" aria-selected="true">Tab Link 1</a></li>
<li class="tab-item tab_id_02a" role="none"><a href="#id_02a" id="label_id_02a" class="tab-link" role="menuitem" aria-selected="false">Tab Link 2</a></li>
<li class="tab-item tab_id_03a" role="none"><a href="#id_03a" id="label_id_03a" class="tab-link" role="menuitem" aria-selected="false">Tab Link 3</a></li>
<li etc.
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("ul li a").each(function () {
           if ($(this).attr("aria-selected") === "true") {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active')
            } else {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active')

            }
        });
```

Comment: Is it that easy? I tried that, but nothing happened. I added: `$(function() {$("li[aria-selected=true]").addClass('active');});`. Also, if someone clicks on one of the other tabs will it check again and removeClass when aria-selected="false"? That was my quandry.

Comment: No you will have to call a function on click of the tabs, that will internally have the above code

Comment: I think your ques is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179413/add-remove-active-class-for-ul-list-with-jquery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Close. $(this) means it adds the "active" class to the ("ul li a"), but the class needs to be added to the ("ul li"). Also when the next tab is clicked the "active" class stays and doesn't remove, nor is "active" added to the new tab. I'll keep fussing with it.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was wondering, if this had to be done with a listener event or just be checking in the background. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, this was solved and worked for me via the previous question at: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179413/add-remove-active-class-for-ul-list-with-jquery) Thanks for your help @Nandita