# How do I add/remove active class for a ul list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When clicked the active class is left with the original "li" where it should have changed. I tried messing with the code but was unable to find a solution. can someone please check what I missed. I think I am mssing something specific to my code. I tried "add/remove active class for ul list with jquery?" but that did not help. If you can find the fault in my code it would be great.

**Html:**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#juk">About</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="myFunction1()">Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdemultimedia/juk/index.html">Wiki/Documentation</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="myFunction()">Screenshots</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Releases </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="ftp://ftp.kde.org/pub/kde/stable/latest">JuK Latest</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/files/src/juk-1.95a.tar.gz">JuK 1.95</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/files/src/juk-1.1.tar.gz">JuK 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/files/src/juk-1.0-1.tar.gz">JuK 1.0</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    ( 'ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li' ).on( 'click', function() {
        $( this ).parent().find( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe you can try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179413/add-remove-active-class-for-ul-list-with-jquery

Comment: `$( 'ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li' )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add/remove active class for ul list with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179413/add-remove-active-class-for-ul-list-with-jquery)

Comment: I tried that but that doesn't help. I think there is something specific to my code that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting the wrong `<li>` element in the `.on('click')` event

You said

```
$( 'ul.nav navbar-nav navbar-right li' )
```

Which will look for `li` that is a child of `navbar-right` that is also a child of `navbar-nav` that is also a child of `ul.nva`.

What you should have targeted is:

```
$( 'ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li' )
```

Notice the space before the `li`? that is because it is a descendant of the `ul` element that has multiple classes.

I know you copied the class list from the HTML DOM element, but you have to avoid spaces in jQuery selector if you are talking about a single element that has multiple classes.

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#juk">About</a></li>
    <li><a>Development</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wiki/Documentation</a></li>
    <li><a >Screenshots</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Releases </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">JuK Latest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JuK 1.95</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JuK 1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JuK 1.0</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much, but unfortunately that does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you try the snippet in my answer? It clearly works for me. @UzairAhmed

Comment: @UzairAhmed You need to know that clicking a link to a different page will cause Javascript to abandon anything it is doing and load that other page immediately. That might be the reason why you don't see the result in your case.

Comment: I did try it, and yes it works here, but it does not when I try it in the actual code. There the active class remains with about.

Comment: The link is to a header on the same page.

Comment: @UzairAhmed try to `console.log()` anything inside the click event to make sure your code is actually running or not.

Comment: If you would like I can send you the link to my code pen.

Comment: @UzairAhmed sure

Comment: @UzairAhmed I found two problems with your codepen. First you forgot to add jQuery library reference, and Second, the selector was not valid . Check my [forked code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXOVYY?editors=1010)