# Implementing toggle state to navbar menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a navbar and dropdown menu for a few of the navbar links. Currently anytime you click on a link on the navbar, it stays toggled permanently, even if you click another link on the navbar, it does not unselect unless you click the same link again. How can I fix this?

Firstly, I want to fix the active class so it would be added/removed properly on the last clicked element only.

The end result should be similar to this navbar:
[example](https://www.mockplus.com/blog/post/drop-down-menu-design)
I want to be able to:

1. click on menu item#1, and show a dropdown for it;
2. click on menu item#1 again, and hide it.

case 2:

1. click on menu item#1, and the dropdown for it;
2. click on any other item#N and hide fir the 1st one;
3. display for the item#N you click on.

     Purchases
  Studies
  Writing
  Education
  Masons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add or change styles, you should add classes. You have already added the `active` class, however, when you click on another link, you have to remove the previously selected one. Please see the results here: or use a snippet: or using a snippet:[example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/UtmostCreator/cv1L8s60/)

As you may see, I have added a `.menu` class to the `ul` element to make it easier for you (`<ul class="menu">`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-btn').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $('.nav-btn').removeClass('active');
      $('.menu > .sub-menu').slideUp();
    } else {
      $('.nav-btn').removeClass('active');
      $('.menu > .sub-menu').slideUp();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $('.menu > .sub-menu').slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-btn').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $('.nav-btn').removeClass('active');
      $('.menu > .sub-menu').slideUp();
    } else {
      $('.nav-btn').removeClass('active');
      $('.menu > .sub-menu').slideUp();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $('.menu > .sub-menu').slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/*main nav*/
.main-nav {
  border-top: #D9D9D9;
  border-bottom: #D9D9D9;
  background: #F4F4F4;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.close-menu {
  margin: 5px;
  display: none
}

.mobile-sidemenu {
  display: none
}

.main-nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  position: relative
}

.main-nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #3D3D3D;
  text-decoration: none
}

.main-nav ul li .drop-ico {
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.main-nav .right-menu-link {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  color: #3D3D3D;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative
}

.main-nav .nav-btn:before,
.main-nav .right-menu-link:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 0;
  transition: .2s;
  height: 4px;
  background: #3D3D3D;
}

.main-nav .nav-btn:hover:before,
.main-nav .nav-btn.active:before,
.main-nav .right-menu-link:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  transition: .2s;
}

.main-nav .nav-btn:hover a,
.main-nav .nav-btn.active a,
.main-nav .right-menu-link:hover {
  color: #3D3D3D
}

/*sub menu*/
.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: -1px 12px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
  z-index: 9;
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #891C5B
}

.main-nav .sub-menu a {
  padding: 8px 0
}

.sub-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sub-menu ul li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

.sub-menu .sub-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.sub-menu .sub-title:before {
  content: '';
  width: 60px;
  background: #C4C4C4;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
}

.sub-menu .menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #EDECEE;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.sub-menu a {
  text-decoration: none
}

.sub-menu .menu-icon img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sub-menu .text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: calc(100% - 65px);
}

.sub-menu strong {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.sub-menu span {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: rgb(0 0 0 / 80%);
  font-weight: 400;
}

.sub-menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub-menu .more-menu {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #4F515FCC;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="main-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-9">
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class="nav-btn">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Purchases</a></li>
              <div class="sub-menu">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-3">
                      <strong class="sub-title">Books</strong>
                      <ul>
                        <li>
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <div class="text">
                              <strong>Test</strong>
                              <span>Dummy text for testing</span>
                            </div>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <li class="nav-btn">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Studies</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-btn">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Writing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-btn">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Education</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-btn">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Masons</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

You could have a look at the similar page here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20179446/6901693

Comment: Hello and thank you! This almost fixed it, but now when clicking one link and then clicking another, it closes the dropdown menu and doesn't open the dropdown of the second link clicked. Check out the jsfiddle I updated it: https://jsfiddle.net/v45q3ykh/6/ It needs to function just like the example here: https://www.mockplus.com/blog/post/drop-down-menu-design

Comment: it causes slideToggle()

Comment: [@rocket129083](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17144244/rocket129083), Please have a look I have updated the code!